# How to set Logistic regression of weka API in java to instances distributions instead of the instances predicted class?

Tags: weka, logistic-regression

I am working on logistic regression classifier of Weka API in java. I want to know How can I set Logistic regression output to instances distributions (the probability to which an instance belongs to class 1) instead of the instances predicted classes? I want to use these to build an ordered list of instances and take top 10 instances.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here: what you intend to do is similar to this:

Click Preprocess Menu,  Click Filter Button, Select "supervised attribute filter", select AddClassification.

[image]

Double-Click on "AddClassification"

Select "Logistic", in the config-dialog: select "Output Distribution", select "true". This will add a new column to your dataset, containing the probabilities for each instance.

If this new column will contain any meaningful data, is another matter. You didn't provide enough information, so I took the built-in "credit-g" dataset

[image]

Note that there are new columns added below the highlighted "class" column:

[image]

The data in these columns look like this:

[image]